# Woocommerce REST api - 401 code ajax authentication

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to use the woocommerce REST API to create a nice shop section to show on my website powered by wordpress. I never used the woocommerce api so I have some doubt about it. As i can understand I need to authenticate every request using the basic authorization. I want tou use jquery ajax but I'm bot able to generate the needed headers and get a response, I will get a 401 error everytime. It works only with postman with oauth 1.0. I'm on localhost for now where I've enabled https. Is there any settings I need to do on my localhost and can anyone show me a correc example of auth with ajax for woocommerce? I was trying to get the categories, but any endpoint will be fine.

```
$.ajax({
 method: 'GET',
 url: 'wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories',
 beforeSend: function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
 },
 success: function(res){
  console.log(res);
 }
});
```

Comment: add `',` after your categories URL!

Comment: @delboy1978uk it's a typo in the question ;)

Comment: ok but basic auth with a base 64user and pass is not an oath token

Comment: The api works also with basic auth as per documentations

Comment: but you cant get that working in Postman, only the OAuth flow?

Comment: yes, with postman works because add the needed auth params to the querystring. As a workaraound I'm thinking to use a php client to take the credential safe and pass then the generated params to the javascript file, but I don't know how, because I think it's needed a dedicated endpoint ?